# Distinct with order by in CosmosDb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

When I run this query

```
SELECT distinct value b
FROM Books b
    JOIN category in b.categories
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(['1','2'], category )
```

it returns distinct 69 records

but when I add order by it returns 100+ records and distinct clause seems to be ignored

```
SELECT distinct value b
FROM Books b
    JOIN category in b.categories
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(['1','2'], category )
order by b.title
```

Is there a way to use distinct along with order by?
(Books collection does not duplicates, they are caused by JOIN)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a solution but it explains the cause:

*'Because cosmos can only return 100 results per page at a time, the distinct keyword will only apply to a single page. So, if your result set contains more than 100 results, you may still get duplicates back - they will simply be on separately paged result sets.'*

(source: [feedback.azure.com](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6719531-provide-support-for-distinct))